# How to make the main method wait for input on GUI without using Listener as a direct trigger?

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, input

I am working on a webscraping tool that should perform various operations with the scraped data.

Because of this, I need various different GUIs to work in an orderly manner and because of that, I need the main method to wait before each has completed it's purpose.

After searching for a while, I have found the following StackOverflow questions that provided some clues on how to solve the problem, but that I could not implement because they have some differences to my case:

[How to wait for input in a text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229788/how-to-wait-for-input-in-a-text-field)
[How to make main thread wait a different thread to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790196/java-how-to-make-this-main-thread-wait-for-the-new-thread-to-terminate)

---

I know I can trigger code using a Listener to a/the GUI's components (a button, for example), but i'm having a hard time making the main-thread wait for that listener to wake it up, while the code for the GUI's thread (when there is one) is initialized by the main thread...

---

This is an simplified code to demonstrate how the program is supposed to work:

```
public class Main {
    /*
     * Waiter is a simple GUI with just an "Start" button in it. Here in place of my actual GUIs.
     */
    private static Waiter auth; //Represents my NTLM-authentication form.
    private static Waiter status; //Represents a status-feedback GUI that will be displayed during processing.
    private static Waiter operation; //Represents a GUI in with the user choses what to do with the gathered data.

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        auth = new Waiter();
        auth.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("NTLM Authentication form. Should wait here until user has filled up the GUI and clicked \"Start\".");
        System.out.println("Authenticates WebClient's NTLM using data inputed to the GUI...");
        auth.dispose();
        Thread srt = new Thread(status = new Waiter());
        srt.start();
        status.setVisible(true);
        //Performs webscraping operations...
        System.out.println("Prepares the webscraped data here...Things like downloading files and/or parsing text...");
        System.out.println("Keeps the user aware of the progress using the \"status\" GUI.");
        status.setVisible(false);
        //Clears the status GUI.
        operation = new Waiter();
        operation.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Operation selection form. Should wait here until user selects an option.");
        System.out.println("Starts performing the operation(s)...");
        operation.dispose();
        status.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Performs the operation(s), while giving status-feedback to the user.");
        status.setVisible(false);
        System.out.println("Displays a file-save dialog to save the results.");
        System.out.println("And finally, displays a \"End of operations\" dialog before ending.");
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE 1:
The main difficulty I'm having is to implement something like this (this is what I want to do):

```
//Main method...code...
Thread srt = new Thread(status = new Waiter());
//Before "srt.start();"...
status.startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    main.continueExecution();
  }
});
//Thread's run() being something like "status.setVisible(true); main.waitGUI();"
srt.start();
//continues here after the Listener is triggered...more code...
```

Instead of this (what is being the solution to most other people, if I'm understanding it right...) (this is what I **don't** want to do, *if possible*):

```
//GUI before this one...
//code...
Thread srt = new Thread(status = new Waiter());
status.startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    /*
     * Code that should come after this GUI.
     */
  }
});
//Thread's run() being something like "status.setVisible(true);"
srt.start();
//"ends" here...(Initial code or GUI before this "status")
```

In other words, I'm having trouble implementing the GUIs and Listeners in a way to trigger main's thread's "sleep" and "wake up" actions, instead of triggering actual processing code.

---

UPDATE 2:

Following @JB_Nizet 's tip on `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`, I took a good look at the [SwingUtilities docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29), and after I found out about how the `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` method works, and I think I've found how to do it, using a combination of `Semaphore` and `invokeAndWait()`.

I need someone with a better understanding of multi-threading and/or GUIs to confirm if it's a safe, valid solution or not. (I'll then edit the question and clean it up, and if confirmed, post this in proper "answer format")

Anyways, here goes the modified code, which seems to be working for me:

```
public class Main_Test {

    //Semaphore:
    public static Semaphore semaphore;
    //GUIs:
    private static Waiter auth; //Represents my NTLM-authentication form.

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
//          semaphore.acquire();
            auth = new Waiter() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(Main_Test.getThread() + this.getName() + " has been created and is now running.");
                        semaphore.acquire(); //Makes main pause.
                        this.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Main_Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            };
            auth.jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(getThread() + "NTLM has been hypothetically authenticated.");
                    semaphore.release(); //Makes main continue after GUI is done.
                    auth.dispose();
                }
            });
//          semaphore.release();
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(auth);
            semaphore.acquire(); //<- Where the main effectively gets paused until the permit is released.
            /*
             * GUI's run() will accquire the semaphore's permit.
             * The invokeAndWait() garantees (?) it will happen before main's acquire().
             * This causes the main to pause when trying to acquire the permit.
             * It stays paused until the actionListener release() that permit.
             */
            System.out.println(getThread() + "This message represents the processing, and should come only after the hypothetical NTLM authentication.");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main_Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main_Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static String getThread() {
        return String.format("%-32s --- ", Thread.currentThread().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bit confusing: Waiter is both a GUI element and a Runnable? Also you seem to be interacting with your GUI from a non GUI thread - that is likely to give unexpected results. You need to give more details about your Waiter object (is it a swing frame? a runnable? etc.)

Comment: Yes, it's a JFrame that implements Runnable. As for non-GUI thread, well, extending the Thread class or implementing Runnable are the methods I'm familiar with; If there is a different, more proper way to do it when it comes to GUIs (/JFrames), you be welcome to pointing me the ways! (tutorials and javadocs about it). ^^

Comment: You should probably read the [Java Tutorial on Swing & Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), especially the part on the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). What you are trying to achieve is not very clear, but you could maybe use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to update your GUI while you run your background tasks.

Comment: I don't know if I could achieve a solution using EDT and SwingWorker, but I have the feeling the answer would be a "no"; I'll try regardless tough. --- What I'm facing is a situation where I have a need for many completely different GUIs throwout the program's execution, and between them, a lot of processing-related code. Because of that, I need the main (processing) code in the main method, and the GUIs showing up along it, when they are needed (user input) or proper (status-feedback to user). Problem: How to make main wait GUI while Listeners act as "continue main", not "exec. this code".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I have completely understood what you want to do, but it seems to me that you have a consumer thread (the main thread, waiting for events from the event dispatch thread), and a producer thread (the event dispatch thread).

The typical way to implement this is to use a blocking queue as a communication mechanism:

- Create a blocking queue
- Create your GUI and pass it the blocking queue
- start a loop which gets data from the queue. Since the queue is blocking, the main thread will be blocked untile there is something in the queue
- Have your event listeners, running in the EDT, post data to the blocking queue

Comment: I'm unsure if that is the case. I'd say my GUIs & main are mutually consuming each-other (?). --- The main thread should firstly create a GUI for NTLM authentication (username, password, proxy, workstation and domain), then wait for the user to input that data, and then, consume it by authenticating it's webclient (a "headless browser" that will be used to webscrap whats nessessary). Then, the main thread will start webscraping, and (create) a "status-feedback" GUI will (consuming main's data) keep the user aware of the progress...Similar main<->GUI interactions happen throwout the program.

Comment: Then you just need a GUI showing several panels or frames one after another, and a SwingWorker to do all the authentication, webscraping tasks in the background. Or you do as I described, and invoke `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` from the main thread to update the GUI from the main thread.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not understanding how I'd implement either of those methodologies in this case. --- The input GUIs are to gather the minimum the program needs for proceeding and can't get by itself. In this case, that is an NTLM-Auth. needed to do webscraping, and what further refinement to do with the scraped data after it has been gathered. Meaning: I "don't need" background-processing for my input GUIs, they are replaced by an output (status) GUI during processing times. --- Anyways, thanks to `invokeAndWait()` I think I've found the trick. See Q. update; I'll be glad if you can confirm it.