# How to wait when the thread is done

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this thread starting :

```
new Thread(Version::new).start();
```

and I have this function

```
setValue();
```

I wouldlike to run the function setValue() after the end of the thread ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: How to make this main thread wait for the new thread to terminate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790196/java-how-to-make-this-main-thread-wait-for-the-new-thread-to-terminate)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Thread.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) method.

However, if your intent is to use the result of a concurrent calculation, using a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CompletableFuture` for that:

```
    Runnable r = ...
    Runnable r2 = () -> setValue();
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(r)
        .thenRun(r2);
```

Answer (score 0):

As i knew the `thread.join()`  will you need

```
public class Main  
{  
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {  
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();  
          
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)  
        {  
            Thread thread = new TestThread();  
            thread.start();  
              
            try  
            {  
                thread.join();  
            }  
            catch (InterruptedException e)  
            {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }  
          
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();  
        System.out.println("sub thread ran ：" + (end - start));  
    }  
}
```